# Good Free Ubuntu Server VMWare Image Needed

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine, apache-http-server, vmware-player

Can anyone recommend a good, free Ubuntu Server VMWare Image (or Virtual Appliance, as they call them)? I have looked on the [VMWare VAM](http://www.vmware.com/appliances/directory/cat/508) and there are literally hundreds to choose from.

I am looking for something that can with very minimal effort serve as a development platform for LAMP applications (so it should have all of those installed, plus things like PhpMyAdmin).

Bonus points if there is some way to create new Virtual Hosts (for developing and testing new sites) on Apache without having to go digging around conf files and guessing on the sytax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Head [straight to Canonical](http://isv-image.ubuntu.com/vmware/) for the VMWare images

Or checkout the the [ThoughtPolice](http://www.thoughtpolice.co.uk/vmware/) folks

Comment: The ones from canonical only go up to 7.10! ThoughtPolice has versions up to Jaunty

Comment: Can the ThoughtPolice images be mounted with VMWare Fusion on the Mac?

Comment: Yes they are compatible.

Comment: The Canonical link is broken, but as an added bonus the ThoughtPolice links include torrent links that are much faster (I'm getting 1MB/s).

Answer (score 2):

If you're running Windows, there's always [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/), which should get you Apache, MySQL, PHP (the -AMP parts), and so on.

Comment: Of course, there's MAMP for Mac OS X as well, but OS X comes preinstalled with Apache and PHP, you just have to install MySQL, which is pretty easy.

Comment: Personally I found the preinstalled Apache and PHP very annoying in OS X.

Comment: Annoying in what way? I do almost all of my development and testing on it; it's extremely convenient.

Answer (score 0):

There is a really easy way to set up a LAMP VM using Ubuntu Server JeOS.  Not a virtual appliance, but very easy to set up if you follow the instructions at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/JeOS

Answer (score -2):

Is it really worth it? I mean, it's not a big deal to create what you need; installation is really fast, and odds are you'll wind up apt-get'ing or aptituding quite a bunch of things anyway...

Comment: I am not a Linux server person, and though I have spent hours digging through Google in the past trying to do what you suggest and get everything configured "just so", I would really like to avoid having to do that if possible. And part of what I want to avoid doing is apt-get'ing and aptitud'ing quite a bunch of things.

Comment: @Yaakov Ellis What makes you think these VMs won't require apt-getting? They're not going to come with everything ever packaged installed - they'll probably be similar to what you'd get if you installed it yourself.

Comment: I think you can save a little time with a base-level appliance since its got all the main apt-get done and tools installed, but you still will need to configure the thing.